# Understanding difference between npx and npm

Tags: npm, npx

I'm struggling to develop a deeper understanding of npx. So in particular the difference between running a commmand with npm and npx. I understand that npx can execute a package from a URL, just one local npm package etc.. But for example here:

```
npx lerna run start --scope frontend --stream
```

What is the difference between

```
npx lerna run start
```

and

```
npm lerna run start
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NPM` - Manages packages but doesn't make life easy executing any.

`NPX` - A tool for executing Node packages.

NPX comes bundled with NPM version 5.2+.

`NPM` by itself does not simply run any package. It doesn't run any package as a matter of fact. If you want to run a package using NPM, you must specify that package in your `package.json file`.

When executables are installed via NPM packages, NPM links to them:

1.`local installs have "links" created at ./node_modules/.bin/ directory.`

2.`global installs have "links" created from the global bin/ directory (e.g.  /usr/local/bin) on Linux or at %AppData%/npm on Windows.`